# Parsing an integer from string and using the value for another selection statement

Tags: java

I'm new to coding and this site.
For this program, I'm accepting 4 different formats for interstate, but when I input Interstate 405, I-405, I405 the values aren't placed into the more information selection statements, while exclusively-digit numbers get accepted and outputted.
I can't seem to find the error to output the extra information for each format inputted.

Sample Output:
Please enter a US interstate highway name.
405
Interstate 405
This is a circumferential highway of highway 5.
Please enter a US interstate highway name.
I-405
Interstate 405
Please enter a US interstate highway name.

Sample Output:2digit
Please enter a US interstate highway name.
40
Interstate 40
This is a long distance arterial highway.
It is also an east-west oriented highway.
Please enter a US interstate highway name.
I-40
Interstate 40
Please enter a US interstate highway name.

---

So when I input "405" it announces that it is a circumferential highway of highway 5 which is different how the extra information isn't outputted when I say I-405, Interstate 405, or I405

```
 import java.util.*;
public class InterstateLoveSong {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String interstate;
      int LENGTH_3_DIGIT_INTERSTATE = 3;
      int INTERSTATE_STR = 11;
      int MODULUS_2DIGIT = 5;
      int DIVIDE_3DIGIT = 100;
      int routeNumber;
      boolean exit;

      do {
          System.out.println("Please enter a US interstate highway name.");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          interstate = in.nextLine();
          {
              //format 1
      if (interstate.startsWith("Interstate")) {
         routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(interstate.substring(INTERSTATE_STR));  
         System.out.println("Interstate " + routeNumber);
      }
      //format 2
      else if (interstate.startsWith("I-")) {
         routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(interstate.substring(2));
         System.out.println("Interstate " + routeNumber);
      }
      //format 3
      else if (interstate.startsWith("I")) {
         routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(interstate.substring(1));
         System.out.println("Interstate " + routeNumber);        
      }
      else if (interstate.length() == LENGTH_3_DIGIT_INTERSTATE) {
         routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(interstate.substring(0));
         System.out.println("Interstate " + routeNumber);  
      }
      else if (interstate.length() == 2) {
         routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(interstate.substring(0));
         System.out.println("Interstate " + routeNumber);  
      }
      else if (interstate.length() == 1) {
         routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(interstate.substring(0));
         System.out.println("Interstate " + routeNumber);  
      }
      else {
         routeNumber = 0;
         System.exit(0);
      }

    //more information for 2 digit highways
    if (interstate.length() <= 2) {     
       if (routeNumber % MODULUS_2DIGIT == 0) {
       System.out.println("This is a long distance arterial highway.");
         }
       if (routeNumber % 2 == 0) {
       System.out.println("It is also an east-west oriented highway.");
         }
       else {
       System.out.println("It is also north-south oriented highway.");
            }  
      } 
    //more information for 3 digit highways
    if (interstate.length() == LENGTH_3_DIGIT_INTERSTATE) {
         if (routeNumber / DIVIDE_3DIGIT % 2 == 0) {
         routeNumber = routeNumber % DIVIDE_3DIGIT;
         System.out.println("This is a circumferential highway of highway " 
         + routeNumber + ".");
         }
         else {
         routeNumber = routeNumber % DIVIDE_3DIGIT;
         System.out.println("This is a spur highway of highway " 
         + routeNumber + ".");
         }
         }
       }    
      }
      while (!interstate.equals("exit"));
    }
 }
```

Comment: There seems to be a copy/paste problem with your code in the `//format 1` block.  Also in `//format 3` this code `routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(innt(interstate.substring(0));` contains unbalanced parentheses, and you haven't shown the method `innt()` that you seem to be invoking (unless that's another copy/paste error).  Please fix the code

Comment: Hint: What does `routeNumber = routeNumber % DIVIDE_3DIGIT;` do before you print out the route number?

Comment: The result of the initial comparison to acquire the route by identifying the format might be a better thing to compare in the "more information" block. It seems like your code should work, but there may be something off about the length of the string.

Comment: Oh, i didn't notice the indentations were off, I'm fixing the code right now.

Comment: I'm thinking I made an error on the more information selection statements. Not sure what though. Can I have more feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex instead

```
Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(interstate);
if( m.matches()) {
   routeNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? I'd say use find, and then m.group(1) should give you the digit string, so the substring thing is not needed.

Comment: Oh! Hah. Eating dinner answering questions. I didn't try it and didn't notice the error. Interger.parseInt(m.group(1)) should work (2 glasses of wine agree!)

Comment: You know, eating and reading/writing while watching TV and listening to music with earphones is very unhealthy. And also, your keyboard will get dirty :)